# JSON parsing using jQuery in API html link

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to write a Jquery to Parse product information from an api.

`<div id="placeholder"></div>`
script....

```
$.getJSON(data);
var output = "<ul>";
for (var i in data.products) {
output += "<li>" + data.products[i].sku + " " + data.products[i].name + "--" + 
data.products[i].salePrice + "</li>";
}
output += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;`
```

when I give var `data = {"products":[{"id_item":12324,"id_name":"canon"}` it works but if I pass a link `var data = "http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(manufacturer=canon&salePrice%3C1000)?format=json&show=sku,name,salePrice&apiKey=<API_KEY>` it does not work. I am a beginner and trying to learn JQUERY. Any kind of help will be appreciated...Is there any code debugger for Jquery... Thanks in advance...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be at all the right format. You need to pass a URL and a callback to `getJSON`, as described here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/. The passed URL will be fetched, and then once the URL is fetched, jQuery will call the callback function, the the fetched data as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting the variable `data` for a URL and using that in the getJSON function then your `data.products` etc.. is not actually referencing anything because `data` is still pointing at your URL.

Take a look at the [getJSON API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) but you'll need to do something like the below.

```
var url = "http://api.remix.bestbu....."
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
   var output = "<ul>";
   for (var i in data.products) {
      etc.....
});
```

**EDIT**

For JSONP you will need to specify the data type using the `$.ajax` function. I'm not aware of a way doing it with `$.getJSON`, someone correct me please if I;m wrong.

```
$.ajax({
   type:"GET",
   dataType: "JSONP",
   url: url,
   success:function(data){
      // .... Your function with the data. 
   }
});
```

Comment: This also appears to be JSONP.

Comment: @Daedalus The documentation I linked is for the function `$.getJSON` which is what is being used. As far as I'm aware the code I've added for receiving JSONP data would work fine... please tell me where I went wrong? Plus I just noticed that the URL states JSON not JSONP, so I'm not even sure that JSONP is relevant here?

Comment: JSONP is for requests outside of the user's domain.  As the user is using an API for an application that is not their own, there is no doubt it is JSONP.  Due to the same-origin policy, one may not make ajax requests to urls outside of the domain the request originated from.  This is where JSONP comes in; a callback variable is appended to the url of the request, which specifies a callback which is then used to retrieve the data.

Comment: @Daedalus Thank you for clarifying but I know what JSONP is and why it's used :) I still fail to see why what I have written is incorrect? If for example in PHP where JSON data was to be returned like so `echo $_GET['callback'].'('.$jsonData.')';` This returns the padded JSON data. So when making an AJAX call with `dataType:'JSONP'` this would get round any cross domain issues.

Comment: It would appear my memory is fuzzy; I really should squash the habbit of commenting on things I'd remember clearly; sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Daedalus No problem, it's good to question things, keeps us all on our toes.

Comment: @vletech Some how it did not work for me, I tried the way you guys suggested....is there way to see the output of $.getJSON() or $.ajax( )..thanks in advance..

Comment: @user2322154 sorry for the delay... to see the output data you can simply use `success:function(data){console.log(data)}`. If I get time tomorrow I will request an API key so I can test what you are trying to do.

Comment: @vletech I think the api is replying CORS header to be null, so I might need to have server side script to pull information from api site.

Comment: @user2322154 I don't think CORS will be effected if the data is being requested client or server side, if the requested domain differs from the source domain then it could be an issue. This seems strange though, is the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header set to 'deny' then?